# Can you use custom objects in a Hibernate filter?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hibernate filter that needs to evaluate using two different columns in the database.  I have another existing hibernate object that contains both of those fields, and I would like to be able to pass the other hibernate object into the session.enableFilter.setParameter() call, rather than pass both the values contained in it separately.

Specifically, I would like to replace this code:

```
session
     .enableFilter("inLocation")
     .setParameter("traversalLeft", 5)
     .setParameter("traversalRight", 10);
```

with this code:

```
session
     .enableFilter("inLocation")
     .setParameter("location", locationHibernateObject)
```

to better insulate excactly what the filter needs.

But when I try to configure the filter like:

```
@FilterDef(name="inLocation", parameters=@ParamDef( name="location", type="com.example.Location" ) )
@Filters( {
    @Filter(name="inLocation", condition="current_location_id in (select location.id from location where location.traversal_left between :location.traversalLeft+1 and :location.traversalRight)")
} )
public class ClassToFilter {
```

I get an error trying to call enableFilter()

Is this something that is even possible?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem it seems.

I am using **hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA**, and my filters and custom types are in one **package-info.java** file. With that setup, the problem seems to be in:

- `org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder#bindPackage()`, where filters are being processed before, rather then after custom types.
- `org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder#bindFilterDef()`, that does not try to discover the custom types at all.

I changed the calling order of methods, and replaced the call in `bindFilterDef()` with:

```
    private static void bindFilterDef(FilterDef defAnn, ExtendedMappings mappings) {
        Map params = new HashMap();
        for (ParamDef param : defAnn.parameters()) {
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // support for custom types in filters
            params.put( param.name(), getType( param.type(), mappings ) );
        }
        FilterDefinition def = new FilterDefinition( defAnn.name(), defAnn.defaultCondition(), params );
        log.info( "Binding filter definition: {}", def.getFilterName() );
        mappings.addFilterDefinition( def );
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // support for custom types in filters
    private static org.hibernate.type.Type getType(String paramType, ExtendedMappings mappings) {
        org.hibernate.type.Type heuristicType = TypeFactory.heuristicType( paramType );
        if ( heuristicType == null ) {
            org.hibernate.mapping.TypeDef typeDef = mappings.getTypeDef(paramType);
            if ( typeDef != null ) {
                heuristicType = TypeFactory.heuristicType( typeDef.getTypeClass(), typeDef.getParameters() );
            }
        }
        log.debug( "for param type: {} parameter heuristic type : {}", paramType, heuristicType );
        return heuristicType;
    }
```

Of course, then I had to build the jar from scratch, but the change seems to solve the problem.

However, in **Hibernate 3.5**, annotation classes are bundled inside **hibernate3.jar**, so more work could be required, since everything has to be built from scratch.

Comment: That definitely makes it sound like a hibernate problem, and not just a configuration I was missing.